# Unable to view debug logs when it has an error

Tags: debugging, debug-logs

Lately, whenever I get a null-pointer exception, I am not able to open the debug log associated with it. I've tried several tools and it always says its been deleted before I can open it, even if I get to it within seconds of the error.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleing all debug logs, are there other users who also have debug logs enabled

Comment: Yes, and I am able to open the logs that don't have errors on them. It's only logs with errors that I can't open

Comment: Try changing debug levels, if there are too many logs, some of them can be skipped. So just disable all that you dont need.

Comment: It's not an issue of the logs being truncated, it's being deleted/won't open at all